# Chance to win a game calculate with Dynamic prorgamming

Tags: algorithm

Assume we have a bag with coins. Some of them have value 1 and same have value 2. It's guaranteed that the bag has at least one coin of value 2. 
Alice and Bob play a game. Alice always starts. You alternately draw a coin and the player who draws the last coin with value 2  wins the game.
Now I am interested in the probability that Alice wins the game if there are x coins with value 1 and y coins with value 2.

I know how to solve this with normal probability theory. But I'm in the process of fully understanding Dynamic programming, so I'm interested in a Dynamic programming approach.

Comment: You did not explicitly state a question. Did you tried anything so far? It's likely that nobody will post an answer without seeing any contribution from your side

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode: count the amount of ways alice and bob win, then you can get probability with that. Using quite a bit of notation abuse like booleans being 0 and 1

```
dp (x1, x2, isAliceTurn):
    if x1 < 0: # last move was not actually a valid move
        return <0, 0>
    if x2 == 0: # game ended
        return <!isAliceTurn, isAliceTurn>
    # we can either remove a coin of type x1 or of type x2   
    return dp(x1 - 1, x2, !isAliceTurn) + dp(x1, x2 - 1, !isAliceTurn)


aliceWins, BobWins = dp(x1, x2, true)
print(aliceWins/(BobWins + aliceWins))
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't see why this is DP solution. Shouldn't it be the other way around a from the smaller cases to the larger to be able to reuse calculations?

Comment: @raeg DP solutions can either be bottom up (smaller cases first, then big) which does not require recursion and needs to be done in a special order and the other type if top down, where you use recursion to solve big problems with smaller ones, and does not require thinking the order you need to do it. This is a top down approach

Comment: You're right, I hadn't thought of that. I don't understand your notation yet. What exactly do you mean by <0,0> and <!isAliceTurn, isAliceTurn> ? Does that mean that I have two variable aliceWins=0 and bobWins=0 and <0,0> at the beginning I add to both 0 and at <!isAliceTurn, isAliceTurn> I add only to one of the two 1 depending on who was just on?

Comment: @raeg isAliceTurn is just a boolean variable, when true <!isAliceTurn, isAliceTurn> is equivalent to <0, 1> (alice looses and bob wins) and when false to <1, 0> (alice wins and bob looses)